# Sibling divs fill vertical space inside wrapper without Flexbox

Tags: html, css

I have two divs inside a wrapper, side by side. One of this divs has more content that the other, and I would like the second to fill the vertical space of the wrapper.

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
outline: 1px solid gray;
  font-size: 0px;
}
.left {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 70%;
  font-size: 16px;
    background: tomato;
}
.right {
    font-size: 16px;
    background: gold;
    width: 30%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">
    This is left
    This is left
    This is left
    This is left
    This is left
    This is left
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    This is right

  </div>
</div>
```

I know how to do that with flexbox, but due to compatibility issues I want to to this without it. Does anyone know how can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with the positioning:

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative; /* added */
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  outline: 1px solid gray;
  font-size: 0px;
}
.left {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 70%;
  font-size: 16px;
  background: tomato;
}
.right {
  position: absolute; /* added */
  height: 100%; /* added */
  font-size: 16px;
  background: gold;
  width: 30%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">
    This is left
    This is left
    This is left
    This is left
    This is left
    This is left
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    This is right

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Of course, `position: absolute;` fills the vertical space when `height: 100%;`… I think using this solution is much better than  `display: table-cell;`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use css Table layout instead.

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  outline: 1px solid gray;
  font-size: 0px;
  display: table;
}

.left {
  width: 70%;
  font-size: 16px;
  background: tomato;
  display: table-cell
}

.right {
  font-size: 16px;
  background: gold;
  width: 30%;
  display: table-cell
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">
    This is left This is left This is left This is left This is left This is left
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    This is right
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you.

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  outline: 1px solid gray;
  font-size: 0px;
  display:table;
}
.left {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 70%;
  font-size: 16px;
    background: tomato;
}
.right {
    font-size: 16px;
    background: gold;
    width: 30%;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">
    This is left
    This is left
    This is left
    This is left
    This is left
    This is left
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    This is right

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If changing the initial `float` behaviour of the elements in question is not preferable, the intended behaviour can also be achieved with *pseudo-elements*

**Code Snippet Demonstration:**

*Note: Content has been set "editable" for the sake of demonstration, add more content to elements by editing them directly*

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  outline: 1px solid gray;
  font-size: 0px;
  position: relative; /* Additional */
}
.left {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 70%;
  font-size: 16px;
    background: tomato;
}
.right {
    font-size: 16px;
    background: gold;
    width: 30%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

/* Additional */
.left:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: tomato;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 70%;
}
.right:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: gold;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left" contenteditable="true">
    This is left
    This is left
    This is left
    This is left
    This is left
    This is left
  </div>
  <div class="right" contenteditable="true">
    This is right
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Very good solution, pseudoelements in `position: absolute` will force the parent element to fill the vertical space of its wrapper… thanks!